# Java - Add all integers from file to ArrayList

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read all integers from a file into an ArrayList in the @BeforeClass of a java JUnit test.  For testing purposes, I am then simply trying to print all values of the arraylist to the screen.  Nothing is being output however.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CalcAverageTest
{

static List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@BeforeClass
public static void testPrep() {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("gradebook.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            intList.add(scanner.nextInt());

        }
        for (int i=0;i<intList.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(intList.get(i));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();   
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }            
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If the file is empty, or doesn’t start with an `int`, nothing will be printed, just as you are experiencing.

Comment: where is your 'gradebook.txt' file located? Is it on the classpath / in the resources directory?
this might be helpful : https://www.programmergate.com/java-read-files-classpath/

Comment: @Fabian Yes it's in the same directory.

Comment: @AJNeufeld you may have hit the nail on the head with your comment.  I have some strings to skip over before the integers.

Comment: I've included an answer, it would be great if you provided the input file as well.

Comment: How does your text file looks like? example: is it a csv or integers are in the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*promoting a comment to an answer*)

If `gradebook.txt` is an empty file, or starts with something that does not parse as an `int`, such as text or comments at the top of the file, then `scanner.hasNextInt()` will immediately return `false`, and `intList` will remain empty.  The `for` loop will then loop over the empty list zero times, and no output will be generated, as observed.

> I have some strings to skip over before the integers.

`scanner.readLine()` can be used to skip over comment lines before the numbers.  If it is not a set number of lines that need skipping, or if there are words on the line before the numbers, we would need to see a sample of the input to advise the best strategy for finding the numbers in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the file till the last line, so you will need to change the condition in the loop and use `.hasNextLine()` instead of `.nextInt()`

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String currLine = scanner.nextLine();
    if (currLine != null && currLine.trim().length() > 0 && currLine.matches("^[0-9]*$"))
        intList.add(Integer.parseInt(currLine));
    }
}
```

Here, we read each line and store it in `currLine`. Now only if it contains a numeric value it is added to the `intList` else it is skipped. *^[0-9]*$* is a regex used to match only numeric values.

From the docs, `hasNextLine()`

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>   This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.

Comment: The code compiled just fine.  The OP is using `hasNextInt()` (which returns a `boolean`) and `nextInt()`, which would work if the file was composed of white space (including new lines) separated numbers.  Based on the comment that there are string at the beginning of the file, your answer would fail with an `InputMismatchException` in the first `nextInt()` call.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Edited the answer.

Comment: Better, but still assumes the numbers are entered one-per-line.  Your code won’t read any line with more than one number.  Looping `while (hasNext())`, and then using `if(hasNextInt())` to discriminate between `int`s (which you would read with `nextInt()`)  and non-`int`s (which you’d skip with `next()`) would be better still. No regex and no `Integer.parseInt()`.  Best would be waiting for a text file sample, so the code can be correct, instead of being WAGs.

Comment: The `currLine != null` test is unnecessary given `hasNextLine()` returned `true`.

Comment: Agreed. We can tweak that accordingly. Let's wait for the input file.

Comment: @AJNeufeld - Also, just using `hasNextInt()` in the while doesn't work. For some reason it gets evaluated to false and the entire loop is skipped.

Comment: Yes, we’ve established that.  See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055579/java-add-all-integers-from-file-to-arraylist#comment93010680_53055579), [OP’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055579/java-add-all-integers-from-file-to-arraylist#comment93010862_53055579), and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53056949/3690024)... in that order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182811/discussion-between-ajneufeld-and-nicholas-k).